# Parsing a one line string containing a math expression, variables, and functions of whitespace in irregular places into tokens

Tags: python, string, parsing, tokenize, shunting-yard

The code I've written is in Python, but the problem isn't Python-specific.

Effectively I'd like to check if a one line string that is meant to represent a mathematical expression comes out to be valid.  I have heard of the **Shunting Yard Algorithm** and I intend to attempt my own version of it after I get over my initial problem which is potential whitespace between operators.

The approach I am taking is to go through character by character and tokenize them based on whether they are valid mathematical symbols or not.  Parentheses get special treatment.

Overall, the approach I came up with *does* work, but I feel there could be some improvements or optimizations.

### Step 1: Get the string into a state that can be tokenized

The symbols I want to use are the basic arithmetic operations: `+-*/` as well as `%` for modular division, `^&|` for bitwise, and later `<<` and `>>` for shifting.

I *also* want to allow functions and user-defined variables in the string so text is *also* valid.

Examples of valid input with operations, functions, and vars:

```
1+sqrt(2)*abc
(sin(3)-cos(4))/def
```

- The first one would tokenize into: `1, +, sqrt(, 2, ), *, abc`
- The second one would tokenize into: `(, sin(, 3, ), -, cos(, 4, ), ), /, def`

### Whitespace complicates things

As stated, the current issue I'm facing is how to deal with whitespace. Using the above examples, the following would also be valid and would evaluate to the previous example after stripping whitespace between symbols:

```
1 + sqrt(2) * abc
( sin(3) - cos(4) ) / def
```

However, doing something like this **would not** due to the space between function name and parentheses:

```
1 + sqrt (2) * abc
```

Also, dealing with wrong input like:

```
1 + sq rt(2)
1 + + sqrt(2)
```

- The first would evaluate to a function called `sq rt()` and would be flagged later as invalid
- The second would create `+ +` and that too would be flagged later as invalid

### Current Process

```
    val = val.strip()
    
    mathTokens = ('+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '^', '&', '|', '~', '<' , '>')
    token = ''
    tokens = []

    mathMode = bool(val[0] in mathTokens)

    for j in range(0, len(val)):
        char = val[j]

        #Left paren
        if(char == '('):
            if(mathMode):
                token = token.strip()
                tokens.append(token)
                tokens.append(char)

            else:
                token += char
                tokens.append(token)

            token = ''
            continue
    
        #Right paren
        if(char == ')'):
            token = token.strip()
            tokens.append(token)
            tokens.append(char)
            token = ''
            continue

        #All others
        if(char == ' ' or (mathMode and char in mathTokens) or (not mathMode and char not in mathTokens)):
            token += char

        else:
            token = token.strip()

            #If a series of spaces only was found, don't append
            if(token):
                tokens.append(token)
            
            token = char
            mathMode = not mathMode
    
    #Append the last token unless it's spaces only (e.g. after right parentheses)
    token = token.strip()
    if(token):
        tokens.append(token)

    print(tokens)
```

##### Sample Input and Result

Here's some sample input (complete with spaces) which is in `val` in the code above:

```
1 + sqrt(2) * abc
```

This gets stored into the `tokens` list as:

```
[
    '1', 
    '+', 
    'sqrt(', 
    '2', 
    ')', 
    '*', 
    'abc'
]
```

### Afterwards

Ultimately, after parsing and figuring out if it's a valid expression then the end result will be fully calculated.  The calculation is going to be the second part of this.  For the calculation, the Shunting Yard algorithm is what I'm thinking of going with.  In general, from what I gather, I can take my tokens and evaluate accordingly.

### Conclusion

As I said at the beginning, this approach does work but constantly doing `strip()` and looking up the symbols feels like it could be slow in situations where there potentially are lots of values to evaluate.  A regex approach sounds like it'd complicate things way too much and I'm not sure if that'd even offer better performance.

Any chance there might be any algorithms for this particular situation and selectively purging whitespace?

I'm also wondering if anything should be changed for potential negative numbers as well.

That's my situation.  Insight appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you please narrow down the scope? There are tons of algorithms for parsing and tokenising, so lots of ways to adjust or replace anything from small to large parts.

Comment: FWIW, practicality I would advise to skip semantic tokenisation completely. It is much simpler to use something like PEG that has an actual concept of grammar while reading than to spread parts of understanding grammar across several steps.

Comment: Hm.  Basically I planned to do it in 2 parts:  The string is provided, it gets parsed into tokens, then I intended to evaluate the tokens with Shunting Yard to get a result.  This was the approach I came up after researching how to do something like this, although the examples I saw are mainly numbers only.

Answer (score -1):

If you only aim at checking the validity, one option is to use [Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to check the validation of e.g. mathematical equations:

```
import ast

def checkEquation(equation):
    try:
        ast.parse(equation)
        return 'valid'
    except SyntaxError:
        return 'invalid'

print( checkEquation('-1 - sqrt(2) * abc') )   #output: valid
print( checkEquation('-1 - sqrt(2 * abc') )    #output: invalid
```